# Combination of 2 random variables that is perfectly correlated with another random variable

Tags: correlation, self-study

I'd appreciate some pointers for the following question: Given 3 random variables $X_i$, $i = 1, 2, 3$ such that none of them have a pairwise correlation of $+1$ or $−1$. Can we find a combination of $X_1$ and $X_2$ that has a correlation of $+1$ with $X_3$?

Comment: This is going to depend on the nature of the underlying relationships amongst these variables. BTW, is this homework? If so, please edit to add the homework tag.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible, but not likely to occur in real life. An artificial example

```
x1 <- rnorm(100)
x2 <- rnorm(100)
x3 <- x1+x2
cor(x1, x2)
cor(x1, x3)
cor(x2, x3)
```

and, of course, since `x3 = x1 + x2`, the correlation between `(x1 + x2)` and `x3` is 1.0.

If you had specified that the three variables are independent, I don't think it's possible, but I am not 100% sure.

Comment: If $X_1$ and $X_2$ are uncorrelated with $X_3$, the linear combination $aX_1+bX_2$ is uncorrelated with $X_3$ since covariance is bilinear.

Comment: The question didn't say $X_1$ and $X_2$ were uncorrelated with $X_3$, just that the correlations weren't 1.0 or -1.0.

Comment: Yes, I was referring to your last line, which talks about what might happen if the variables are pairwise independent, hence uncorrelated.

Comment: Oh, sorry. Cool, thanks for that. That was my intuition, but it's nice to know I was right. :-).